# Usage of worker threads in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

```
//Case I : ( It works but not sure if it is safe . Is it because the windows
             messages are handle in a process queue already? )
void MyDlg::OnClickButton1()
{
     std::thread([]()
     {
          // some long computation here

         SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_TEXT, L"Updated");
     }).detach();
}



//Case II : ( It works . But is the process_queue redundant ) 
void MyDlg::OnClickButton1()
{
     std::thread([]()
     {
          // some long computation here

         command_node node =   
         command_factory("SetDlgItemText",IDC_STATIC_TEXT, "Updated");

         SendMessageToMyProcessQueue(node);         
     }).detach();
}
void MyDlg::OnPaint()
{
       ExecuteFromMyProcessQueue();
       CDialogEx::OnPaint();
}
```

This is a sample snippet in VC++ using MFC and I want to use a worker thread to complete a task and send the result to a control. Which on is desirable or any other work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MFC: accessing GUI from another thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462347/mfc-accessing-gui-from-another-thread)

Comment: Not duplicate. Earlier thread was concerned only with the case I and the advisories were prohibiting use of worker thread in MFC GUI thread. Case II of my query tries to explore a work around to the situation by using a asynchronous priority queue and allow main GUI thread to process the post messages

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good idea (or required) to refrain from accessing the GUI directly from other threads than the main thread. MFC might assert or it might not, depending on how consistent it is implemented. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462347/mfc-accessing-gui-from-another-thread). So that rules out your first case.

Using message queues is the safe and correct way to do it. See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391125/how-to-change-pane-text-of-status-bar-from-a-thread-in-mfc) on how to update the UI from another thread.